# Number of positive integers that do not contain the digit $9$

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that if $f(n)$ is the number of positive integers $k \leq n$ that do not contain the digit $9$, then $f(10^m) = 9^m$ for all $m \geq 1$.

I was thinking of using induction but then how do we determine the number of integers between $10^k$ and $10^{k+1}$ with no $9$ digit?

Comment: What's a way to turn a $k$ digit number into a $k+1$ digit number? How many of those will have $9$s?

Comment: In principle it probably requires induction, but unless induction is specified, I think a more informal counting argument is better.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as the number of non-negative integers $\le 10^m-1$ that have no $9$'s.

Any integer from $0$ to $10^m-1$ can be thought of as a string of $m$ digits by "padding" numbers with fewer than $m$ digits with initial $0$'s. For example, if $m=4$, we can think of $12$ as $0012$.

So we want to count the digit strings of length $m$ that have no $9$'s.

The first digit can be chosen in $9$ ways. For every such choice the second digit can be chosen in $9$ ways. So the first two digits can be chosen in $9^2$ ways. For every such choice, the third digit can be chosen in $9$ ways. So the first three digits can be chosen in $9^3$ ways. And so on (here we have a hidden induction). So the $m$ digits can be chosen in $9^m$ ways.

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking of using induction

Good idea.  Go with that.

> but then how do we determine the number of integers between $10^k$
>    and $10^{k+1}$ with no 9 digit?

You likely mean those within $\{10^k+1, .., 10^{k+1}\}$ , since we don't wish to include the end of the last interval to avoid overcounting.

You are counting all of the $k$ digit strings where the first digit is selected from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7, 8\}$ and each of the other $k-1$ are selected from $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$; noting that the selection is independent ("allows repetition").  Then exclude that consisting of one and $k$ zeroes, but include the one consisting of one and $k+1$ zeroes.

> $$f(10^{k+1})-f(10^k) = 8\cdot 9^{k-1}$$

Now, you can continue with your induction proof.

Comment: There is also another interesting question you can ask. What does the sum of the inverses of such numbers converge to?